# How to Extract the Name 'Terence Crawford' from an HTML Segment, Excluding the Span Element?

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I am currently facing difficulty retrieving the name 'Terence Crawford' from an HTML segment. The challenge lies in excluding the span element, which is present within the same parent element.

```
<td colspan="3" style="position:relative;" class="defaultTitleAlign">
<h1 style="display:inline-block;margin-right:5px;line-height:30px;">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold;"><i class="fas fa-crown" style="color:#f6b501 !important;"></i></span>
                    "Terence Crawford"
    </h1>
<div style="width:100%;position:relative;margin-top:5px;">
</div>
</td>
```

I attempted to retrieve the name by specifying both the class attribute 'defaultTitleAlign' and the style attribute 'display:inline-block;margin-right:5px;line-height:30px;', but it only returns '/n' instead of the actual name. Even when targeting the entire content of the h1 element, the name is not being displayed.

```
In [9]: response.xpath("//td[@class='defaultTitleAlign']/h1/text()").get()
Out[9]: '\n                        '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getall()` method to collect all of the `text()` from the given selector, then you can will find the section you are looking for in the returned list.

For example:

```
In [1]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

In [2]: html = """<td colspan="3" style="position:relative;" class="defaultTitleAlign">
   ...: <h1 style="display:inline-block;margin-right:5px;line-height:30px;">
   ...:                         <span style="font-weight:bold;"><i class="fas fa-crown" style="color:#f6b501 !important;"></i></span>
   ...:                     "Terence Crawford"
   ...:     </h1>
   ...: <div style="width:100%;position:relative;margin-top:5px;">
   ...: </div>
   ...: </td>"""

In [4]: response = Selector(text=html)

In [5]: text_list = response.xpath("//td[@class='defaultTitleAlign']/h1//text()").getall()

In [6]: text = text_list[1].strip()

In [7]: text
Out[7]: '"Terence Crawford"'
```